# ServiceActivationException (500) posting newsfeed

Tags: sharepoint-server, error

In my very new, lab install of SharePoint 2013 in Windows 2012, I get this error message when trying to post to the newsfeed

SharePoint returned the following error:

> Unexpected response from
>   server. The status code of response is '500'. The status text of
>   response is 'System.ServiceModel.ServiceActivationException'. Contact
>   your system administrator for help in resolving this problem.

So far, I have:

- Checked that the `ASPNetCompatibilityEnabled = true`
- Checked the memory (50% free memory).
- Changed performance level (`Set-SPEnterpriseSearchService -PerformanceLevel Reduced` as mentioned [here](http://sharepointthing.wordpress.com/2012/11/18/sharepoint-2013-unexpected-response-from-server-the-status-code-of-response-is-500-the-status-text-of-response-is-system-servicemodel-serviceactivationexception/).
- Disabled MDS (`Disable-SPFeature -Identity 87294C72-F260-42f3-A41B-981A2FFCE37A -Url XXX`).

Those changes haven't helped.

Comment: what about the Distributed cache? is Cache cluster up and running? try to reset it then test it.

Comment: @WaqasSarwarMCSE: Thanks. The Distributed Cache is running (I restarted it anyways). No luck. Is there any way to get more information in some log or something? the error message is really obscure.

Comment: enable the verbose logging and then try to reproduce the issue.

Comment: Ok. That helped.

Comment: you get more details about the error and are you able to fix it?

Comment: See my answer. My wildcard inclusion was not properly setup. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Got the same issue because of **RAM** is Full. so i restarted SQL Server that resolves my issue.

Answer (score 0):

After following the suggestion to use verbose logging I found that

> A failure was encountered while attempting to create the site,
>   wildcard inclusion used to create personal sites does not exist

I added the wildcard on the site and now the newsfeed is working (still need to fix other things but this helped).

I used [this information](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee748656(v=office.15).aspx#section3) to setup the logging.

Answer (score 0):

- Just check your Developer tools Console (press F12 in broser)
- for me it was calling the some SharePoint client.svc at below address
  `http://XXXXXXX:82/Test/_vti_bin/client.svc/ProcessQuery`
- and when opened in the browser it was complaining about like below
  error

  ```
  A binding instance has already been associated to listen URI
  ```

  `http://XXXXXX:82/_vti_bin/client.svc`. If two endpoints want to 
  share the same ListenUri, they must also share the same binding object instance.
   The two conflicting endpoints were either specified in `AddServiceEndpoint()` calls, in a config file, or a combination of `AddServiceEndpoint()` and config.
- finnaly removing application and recreating on another port and
  attaching the WSS_contents resolved the problem

Answer (score 0):

To add to the answer above, you can include the wildcard for the personal sites by doing the following:

Run `Get-SPManagedPath -HostHeader`

If this does not show

> personal WildcardInclusion

in the results then enter the command

```
New-SPManagedPath -RelativeURL "personal" -HostHeader
```

Run `Get-SPManagedPath -HostHeader` again to ensure that that has been added

Full details can be found [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/josrod/2013/12/16/wildcard-inclusion-used-to-create-personal-sites-does-not-exist/)

Answer (score 0):

When I restarted "SharePoint Search Host Controller" service it worked for me. May be due to less space on "C" drive hard disk causes a issue.

Answer (score 0):

I restarted "**SharePoint Search Host Controller**" in the **services** and it started working for me.

Before I restarted it, the memory utilization was 100% which was causing the issue